# Is it possible to access java beans in selenium tests?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, javabeans, jsf-1.2

We are currently developing a trade project with Richfaces 3.0, Seam 2.2 and JBOSS 6.0. And we are using Selenium for our GUI tests. I just want to know if there is any possibilty to access beans in selenium tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Selenium and Seam beans are a completely different level of abstraction. Seam beans are running inside a JBoss server while Selenium works on top of a web browser.

If you want to somehow control the application from the inside, you must provide some interface for these beans that is accessible via Selenium test. For instance you might expose some operations as web services or JMX beans and access them from Selenium test suite if written in Java.

Note however that this is not the best practice - Selenium tests should only work on user interface (end-to-end) level. Try to setup your application only via the user interface rather than manually accessing application internals.

UPDATE: If you have some common setup (like users, products, etc.), insert them in your database as part of your common deployment infrastructure. Then you can have a single test for creating/accepting a user, adding product, etc. and then simply reuse the common users already existing in the database.

Comment: The OP is not asking about Spring beans, I think he's talking about POJOs.

Comment: Ashkan Aryan the premise is still correct. Selenium is about in browser UI testing and should not interact with the server (and its beans) directly.

Comment: @James DW yes that's correct, I have pointed out the same in my answer (see below), just pointing out that Spring is not in the mix here.

Comment: My mistake, thanks. I accepted *James DW* edit changing to *Seam beans*. However the answer in general was still valid.

Comment: I'm just wondering. I know that is not a good practice. But we think maybe it gives us a chance to skip some steps as i commented to previous answer.

Comment: i'm accepting this answer for good explanation. Also there is no need to leave this question unanswered. Maybe we should create more test suits. Also thanks to Ashkan Aryan too.

Comment: We did something like, as you mentioned in you update, in our company registry tests. I think we must create some for other tests too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing technically stopping you from allowing selenium visibility to your beans and call methods on them directly. However, it won't be a good design practice. Selenium is for testing the behaviour of your applications (through GUI, mostly) and should not be concerned with bean level. Maybe if you give us a use case of why you may need to do so it may make sense?

In the past I have exposed web services and JDBC tests via selenium as a shortcut for QA people to test certain parts of the application, if that's what you are talking about, but it may be best to use it via web services as Tomasz mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for response. This use case makes us to think if my question senses: We have a trade application. And companies register themselves to us. And an admin roled user comfirms them. After comfirmation user can login and user can perform what our application is for. For every test case about comfirmed user, user needs to log in first, this increases our test times. (login longs between 10-20 secs for each test) And that makes us to think maybe we can skip this step like in Seam Tests.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious: why do you need to log in first at the beginning of each test case? Is it not possible to refactor your tests in a way to log in once? Also another strategy would be to "mock" the login operation in the test environment (using a fake controller in the back-end or something like that) which will return quicker.

Comment: im correcting "each test" thing. Not for each test. Just for comfirmed user operations tests. We already wrote suits but for tests in suits?